# Excel Macro Help: Start at R 2, read Col B, WS 1, find same in Col E, WS 2, then copy cell in Col I, WS 1 into cell of Col G, WS 2

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Need to make a Macro in excel to do this:

Starting at Row 2, read Column B, Worksheet 1,(need to Prefix data with PW- and trim spaces at end of string) 
find same value in Column E, Worksheet 2, 
having matched rows copy cell contents in Column I, Worksheet 1 into cell of Column G, Worksheet 2
move to row 3, column B, worksheet 1 and so on

[Worksheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2ptI.jpg)

Data in Column B, Worksheet 1 = "5555BGR32   "
needs to be converted to "PW-555BGR32" before trying to search worksheet 2 (prefix PW- and remove spaces)

[Worksheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHRxu.jpg)

hope that makes it clear
Russell

Worksheet 1 = SohGB.csv
Worksheet 2 = Stockimport.xlsm

Macro code:

```
Sub Macro1()  
'Import sohGB sheet  
    ChDir "/"  
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\work\sites\Solve-NT\Gorilla Workwear\Suppliers\Portwest Stock feed\sohGB.csv"  
    Sheets("sohGB").Select  
    Sheets("sohGB").Copy Before:=Workbooks("Stockimport.xlsm").Sheets(1)  
    Windows("sohGB.csv").Activate  
    ActiveWindow.Close  
' Find last row  
    Sheets("sohGB").Select  
      With ActiveSheet  
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  
    End With  
' LOOP  
'pick up data from sohGB  
        For x = 2 To LastRow  
        Sheets("sohGB").Select  
        Item = Cells(x, 2)  
        Item = Trim(Item)  
        Item = "PW-" & Item  
        StockLevel = Cells(2, 9)  
'Find Item Stockimport  
            Sheets("Stockimport").Select  
              Columns("E:E").Select  

           FoundCell = Selection.Find(What:=Item, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
                xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows,  SearchDirection:= _
                xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate  
            If FoundCell Is Nothing Then  
                 GoTo NotFound  
            End If  
           'Overwrite stock level  
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = StockLevel  
NotFound:  
    Next x  
End Sub
```

when ran this macro errors with this
[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC1Vu.jpg)
[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGd8Q.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: So now you need to [edit] the question to include the macro as code, not an image. And please explain why the macro is not working. What are the errors?

Comment: Your error is because you are trying to `.Activate` a cell but it was not **Found**.  This is one of  many reasons you should not be using `Select` and/or `Activate`.

Comment: Can you point me at what i should be using instead then please

Comment: It has to `SET FoundCell = Selection.Find(...` because you are setting a range object, not assigning a value. You also might need to use `On Error Resume Next` before that line and `On error goto 0` after it. Also `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = StockLevel` should probably be `FoundCell.Offset(0, 2) = StockLevel` and you should avoid using `.Select` and `Selection`. I believe `Item` is a reserved word that shouldn't be used as a variable's name.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `StockLevel = Cells(x, 9)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the promised rewrite. I wasn't able to fully test bench the code but it does compile without error.

**Edit:** I've made one additional improvement that simplifies the code further.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

    'Declare your variables!
    Dim x As Long, lastRow As Long, stockLevel As Long
    Dim cRef As String, foundAt As Variant

    With Workbooks("StockImport.xlsm")

        'you can directly insert a CSV as a worksheet if you treat it as a template
        'note: must be Sheets.Add, not Worksheets.Add
        .Sheets.Add Before:=.Sheets(1), _
                    Type:="C:\work\sites\Solve-NT\Gorilla Workwear\Suppliers\Portwest Stock feed\sohGB.csv"

        ' Find last row
        With .Worksheets("sohGB")
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        End With

        ' LOOP
        For x = 2 To lastRow

            'record child reference and stock level
            With .Worksheets("sohGB")
                'Trim only removes leading/trailing spaces; it doesn't remove interim spaces
                cRef = "PW-" & Replace(.Cells(x, "B").Value2, Chr(32), vbNullString)
                stockLevel = .Cells(x, "I").Value2
            End With

            'Find Item in Stockimport
            With .Worksheets("StockImport")

                'alternate method of location
                foundAt = Application.Match(cRef, .Range("E:E"), 0)

                If Not IsError(foundAt) Then

                    'set new stock level
                    .Cells(foundAt, "G") = stockLevel

                End If

            End With

        Next x

    End With

    'I wasn't sure what this was supposed to do so I put it here. It's not needed above.
    ChDir "/"

End Sub
```